# Error when putting link in PHP-generated email

Tags: php, html, email

i am trying to send html text to email using php i write code for only message part below

```
$message="<html><body> 
<div><b>Title</b>:$app $vesion </div>
<div><a href="http://localhost/download/row[3]">Install Team Provisioning File</a>
</div> <br/>
<div><a href="http://localhost/download/row[5]">install binary</a>
</div>
 <div><b>Released</b>:$date</div> 
<body>
<html>";
```

but it shows error syntax error, unexpected T_STRING at a href part 
please suggest me for how append a herf in $message

Comment: For long strings that contain quotes and apostrophes, [heredoc syntax](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/3) may be handy. (http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your double-quotes with \"

```
$message="<html><body> 
<div><b>Title</b>:$app $vesion </div>
<div><a href=\"http://localhost/download/row[3]\">Install Team Provisioning File</a>
</div> <br/>
<div><a href=\"http://localhost/download/row[5]\">install binary</a>
</div>
 <div><b>Released</b>:$date</div> 
<body>
<html>";
```

Also, is row[3] and row[5] a PHP var?  If so, it needs a `$` in front.

Answer (score 2):

The internal quotations, in the href=... part are closing the wrapping quotes.  Try this:

```
$message="<html><body> 
<div><b>Title</b>:$app $vesion </div>
<div><a href='http://localhost/download/" . $row[3] . "'>Install Team Provisioning File</a>
</div> <br/>
<div><a href='http://localhost/download/" . $row[5] . "'>install binary</a>
</div>
 <div><b>Released</b>:$date</div> 
<body>
<html>";
```

Comment: You don't need to end your quotes to use a variable when dealing with double quotes. You only need to do that if you're using the single quotes. `echo "something $var";` is the same as `echo "something " . $var;` which is different from `echo 'something $var';`